# ¿Cómo pasarle la función para eliminar registros con una ventana modal en Django?

Tags: python, django, ajax

Lo que quiero lograr es eliminar registros con un modal en vez de redirigir al usuario a otra página donde confirme la eliminación.

[image: eliminar con vetana modal en Django]

```
class RBMidentificadorDeleView(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Identificador
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lsitar_identificador')
    template_name = 'identificadores/elim.html'
    success_message = 'Identificador %(nombre)s Eliminado'
```

Mi URL:

```
url(r'^dele/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RBMidentificadorDeleView.as_view(), name='eliminar_identificador'),
```

Mi template donde quiero eliminar:

```
<div class="row">
    {% for identificador in lista_identificador %}      
        <div class="col s13 m3">
            <div class="card white" id="datos_identi">
                <div class="card-content purple-text">
                    <span class="card-title titulo-ide-comun">Identificador <span class="titulo-ide">{{identificador.clave}}</span></span>
                    <p>{{identificador.nombre}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                    <a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1" >Eliminar</a>
                    <a href='{% url "editar_identificador" identificador.id %}'>Actualizar</a>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form action='{% url "eliminar_identificador" identificador.id %}'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h3>estas apunto de eliminar {{identificador.clave}}</h3> 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cancelar</a>
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Eliminar</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: En realidad, desde el frontend no eliminas nada. Desde el modal llamas a la función que elimina el registro. Pides ciertas acciones en el frontend y muestras código del backend. Aclara tus conceptos y modifica tu pregunta para que sea coherente con lo que quieres.

Comment: Gracias, tendré más cuidado

Comment: Hola, ¿cual es el problema con tu código?

Comment: No logro eliminar registros con una ventana modal. El código que puede es lo que tengo, pero no tengo la mínima idea como eliminar registros con una ventana modal, logro hacerlo pero enviando al usuario a otro html... Y ahí confirma si desea eliminar

Comment: Acabo de publicar una respuesta, espero te ayude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview) no vas a poder lograr lo que quieres, en realidad esa clase no te va a servir de nada para lo que quieres lograr. Lo que necesitas es una función AJAX.

Lo que normalmente hago yo es crear un archivo llamado justamente `ajax.py`. Entonces, ya no es necesario usar un formulario ya que los datos se lo vas a pasar por jQuery (si no lo estás usando te recomiendo que lo hagas).

Tu modal quedaría más o menos así:

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h3>estas apunto de eliminar {{identificador.clave}}</h3> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Cancelar</a>
        <button onclick="eliminarIdentificador('{{ identificador.id }}')" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Eliminar</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function eliminarIdentificador(identificadorId) {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'eliminar_identificador' %}",
            data: {
                "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
                "identificador_id": identificadorId                    
            },
        });
        request.done(function(response) {
            alert("Identificador eliminado");
            // Cierra el modal, oculta el identificador eliminado, etc.
        });
    }
</script>
```

Algunas cosas que notar:

- He cambiado la acción de eliminar a un `<button>` y le he agregado el evento `onclick` que llama a la función que finalmente eliminará el registro mediante AJAX

  ```
  <button onclick="eliminarIdentificador('{{ identificador.id }}')" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Eliminar</a>
  ```
- Ya no hay un formulario dentro del modal
- Al hacer el POST mediante AJAX le estoy pasando como parámetro adicional el `csrf_token`

  ```
  var request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{% url 'produccion:validar_pallet' %}",
      data: {
          "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
          "identificador_id": identificadorId                    
      },
  });
  ```
- Al eliminar el registro sería ideal que de alguna forma cierres el modal  y ocultes o elimines el `div` del identificador que has eliminado. Eso es tarea tuya

Bien, ahora lo que necesitamos es la URL y la función AJAX en Python para eliminar finalmente el registro.

La URL sería:

```
from .ajax import eliminar_identificador

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'eliminar_identificador/$', eliminar_identificador, name='eliminar_identificador')
    # ...
]
```

Y la función en tu archivo `ajax.py`:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

from .models import Identificador


def eliminar_identificador(request):
    pk = request.POST.get('identificador_id')
    identificador = Identificador.objects.get(pk=pk)
    identificador.delete()
    response = {}
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

Comment: logre a ser que elimine con ajax, pero no pude desde la ventana modal

Answer (score 1):

El error está en querer usar `identificador.id` en el action del form dentro del modal que está fuera del **for**. Prueba pasar el action mediante alguna función en javascript al momento de hacer clic en el botón **Eliminar**.